# Media links broken after migration from PC to PC with GRAMPS

Tags: gramps

I have the following problem (not a bug!) when using [GRAMPS](https://gramps-project.org/) on Linux (or perhaps it is just me not knowing how to use it properly).

I was migrating my system to another pc and - after a backup with ALL my data including all media files - I run into the issue that Gramps creates a new folder, like `NAMEOFTREE_2013-10-07.gpkg.media/Familytree/Docs/...` in my home folder, instead of preserving the original folder structure, which was `Familytree/Docs/...`. When I now copy the folder `/Familytree/Docs/...` from `NAMEOFTREE_2013-10-07.gpkg.media`, then all media links are broken.

Is there a way to easily conduct a complete migration with GRAMPS with all data including media from one PC to another (I have not found out yet)?

Comment: You can reset the base path for media to whatever directory you want, as shown here https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps_4.1_Wiki_Manual_-_Settings

Comment: Ah, ok. After I did this will this be always the media path directory as soon as I copy the gramps config.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the base path for media to whatever directory you want, as shown in the [Gramps 4.1 Wiki Manual - Settings](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps_4.1_Wiki_Manual_-_Settings). The setting is found in:
`Preferences` > `General` > `Base path for relative media paths`

You should copy everything to the new PC before making any changes to settings. There shouldn't be any need to copy, move, or edit the config file separately.